# (Service) Function not working on button press

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I seem to be having an issues using a service. I created a controller file and added a service above it. I injected the service into the controller and am trying to access one of the service's functions. I am calling the function using a button. The problem is when I press the button nothing happens. I have tried testing the result by outputting to the console but nothing is working.

Here is some of the controller, the rest doesn't matter to the example.

```
var app = angular.module('DonationWebApp');

app.service('candidateId', function() {
    var candidateID = 0;

    var addID = function(id){
        candidateID = id;
    };

    var getID = function() {
        return candidateID;
    };

    return {
        addID : addID,
        getID : getID
    }

});


app.controller('candidatesController', ['$scope','$location', '$http', function($scope, $location, $http, candidateId) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Here are all the candidates';


    findAll();
    findSupporters();
    var display = true;
    var isHidden = true;

    $scope.addCandidateID = function(id) {
        candidateId.addID(id);
    }
}]);
```

and here is the button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addCandidateID(candidate._id)">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Edit
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things you will definitely need to change first:

You need to add `[]` after your app definition so it will be:

```
var app = angular.module('DonationWebApp', []);
```

You need to include `candidateId` in your array of dependencies in your controller definition:

```
app.controller('candidatesController', ['$scope','$location', '$http', 'candidateId', function($scope, $location, $http, candidateId) {
  ...
}]);
```

Here is an example [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kKQI2IjDQwgZoaWu33aX?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
   var app = angular.module('DonationWebApp',[]);
   app.service('candidateId', function() {
    var candidateID = 0;

    var addID = function(id){
        candidateID = id;
    };

    var getID = function() {
        return candidateID;
    };

    return {
        addID : addID,
        getID : getID
    }

  });

          app.controller('candidatesController',  function($scope, $location,    $http, candidateId) {
            // create a message to display in our view
         $scope.message = 'Here are all the candidates';


         findAll();
         findSupporters();
        var display = true;
        var isHidden = true;

         $scope.addCandidateID = function(id) {
         candidateId.addID(id);
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

https://plnkr.co/edit/OsnmPzMTkBb88JrxacjL?p=preview

I got a minimal sample working in plunkr.

You did not inject the service into your controller:

```
    app.controller('candidatesController', ['$scope','$location', '$http', 'candidateId', function($scope, $location, $http, candidateId) {
   ...
    }]);
```

You have to declare the names of the services your controller needs in the array. This is because js minimizers like uglifyjs sometimes mangle parameter names, but angular needs to know the names of the services so it can locate them. You requested the candidateId service, but did not declare it as an import.

I also had to update your module declaration:

```
var app = angular.module('DonationWebApp', []);
```

The empty array tells angular that you are declaring a new module that has no dependencies (the array is a list of dependencies). Without the array, angular looks for an existing module named DonationWebApp and doesn't find it.

If this doesn't help, we would need to see a more full example or see what error messages you are getting.

The controller you posted doesn't seem complete so I had to speculate on what your data model might look like. Make sure you spelled everything correctly in your template.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have multiple controllers and each have var app = angular.module('DonationWebApp'); at the top. So when I input [] into the module at the top, nothing appears on the website. my ng-app="DonationWebApp" on my index view.

Comment: There needs to be exactly one place with angular.module('DonationWebApp', []); This actually creates the module. The rest don't need the [], and they look up a reference to the existing module.

Comment: ahh yes I see what you mean. I only have one problem with that lol I have a controller called AngularApp.js that has var app = angular.module('DonationWebApp', ['ngRoute']);. So im assuming that when i insert the [] it overwrites the module inside of AngularApp.js. This means that my routes to different pages wont work.

Comment: Sounds like you have the module declarations right. Leave them alone. Do you have an element with ng-controller="candidatesController" in your template? Does {{message}} in the template show anything?

Comment: Yes each of my pages has a controller

Comment: If not, please update with a more complete sample so we can help.